# EF6 Fluent API Map Related Entities On Custom Key/Properties Not PK

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have the following models

```
public class Rate
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } // PK
    public int SpecialId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "Money")]
    public decimal Rental { get; set; }
    public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

And the following...

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } // PK
    public int SpecialId { get; set; }

    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }

    // List of rates on
    public virtual ICollection<Rate> Rates { get; set; }
}
```

So a Rate would have a vehicle and a vehicle could have a list of rates. Normally I just map using the PK's and EF works great.

However on this occasion I need to map/join them using the SpecialId. I started with the following on the Rate Mapping class, but can only map one side of the join. How do I tell it not to use the PK id but the SpecialId for both sides?

```
 HasKey(x => x.Id);
 Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired();
 Property(x => x.SpecialId).IsRequired();
 HasOptional(x => x.Vehicle).WithMany(x => x.Rates).Map(m => m.MapKey("SpecialId"));
```

Is there a way to use SpecialId on both the Rate and Vehicle table to join the two. Maybe another overload on that .Map() method?

Comment: It seems to me without fully knowing your domain that one of those ids should go. Both seems to be PK-class properties. Maybe there is a way to convert to the PK when doing the mapping?

Comment: @MikaelEliasson the special id is needed to tie together the rates to the vehicle. The 'Id' is just so each record has a unique Id so I can pull it out and delete individually if and when needed. I don't see how I could lose one? I was looking a composite keys in EF but I don't think that is correct?

Comment: But is the SpecialId on the Vehicle unique or can two vehicles have the same SpecialId?

Comment: @MikaelEliasson SpecialId on the vehicle will be unique.

Comment: Then I don't get the reason for not using a normal 1-N relationship. On rate it would change from ´´´SpecialId:int =>  VehicleId:Guid´´´ and delete SpecialId on the Vehicle.

That maps to a normal FK. The only slight drawback I can see from what   you describe is if you enter relationsships manually because GUIDs pretty much need copy & paste.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is not supported in EF 6.x and previous versions, but in EF 7 it was called **[Alternate Key](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Seth-Juarez/Alternate-Keys-in-Entity-Framework-7)**. In your case it would be:

```
Entity<Rate>().Reference(r=>r.Vehicle)
              .InverseCollection(v=>v.Rates)
              .ForeignKey(r=>r.SpecialId)
              .PrincipalForeignKey(v=>v.SpecialId);
```

Comment: I do think this is correct. But for querying you don't really need to map a relationship. You can query it using joins anyway. If you need the foreign key constraints you can add that manually in a migration or similar.